# Count unique values in Python list

Tags: python, list

I have the following code I've been working on, but I can't seem to find a way to count the number of unique values in the anagram list. If I just print out: `print len(anagram)` I get the total value of the list, but it includes duplicates.

I have tried to convert the list to a set and back to get rid of the duplicates, but have not had any luck.

Thanks!

```
#import libraries 
import urllib, itertools

#import dictionary
scrabble = urllib.urlopen('http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/ospd.txt').read().split()
#print the length of the dictionary
print len(scrabble)

#make anagrams from scrabble list
anagrams = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(scrabble, key=sorted), key=sorted)]


#print the largest anagram  
print "Largest number of anagrams for a word : ", len(max(anagrams, key=len)) 
print "Largest anagram word and values ", max(anagrams, key=len)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `set`. `set`s hold only unique values:

```py
print(len(set(anagram)))
```

Comment: I received the following error when I ran that code:    

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Ah. You'll want to use `tuple(g)` instead of `list(g)`, since `list`s cannot be placed into sets (as they are mutable).

Comment: Thank you! It worked! It returned the value 65783, which seems a little high given that the list is contained 79339 values.